# How to change gpio directory for node.js pi-gpio?

Tags: gpio, node.js

I was wondering how to change the gpio directory for the node.js pi-gpio library. Whenever I try to run the script to change the pin it returns this error:

"Error when trying to open pin 40

gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership of /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio21/direction: No such file or directory"

Comment: The source code is here: https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin/blob/master/src/gpio-admin.c.  You could clone that project and edit the path, get that project onto your device and then rebuild it.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure how to exactly go about that and the link you posted is a 404 error. Do you know of any other way to interface with the GPIO pins through node.js

Answer (score 3):

When the latest package raspberrypi-bootloader:armhf 1.20150130-1 was installed, the gpio symbolic links in /sys/class/gpio/ moved from /sys/devices/virtual/ to /sys/devices/soc/20200000.gpio.

#### Solution 1

```
chmod -R +x /sys/devices/soc/20200000.gpio
```

#### Solution 2

Update the pi-gpio.js so that

```
sysFsPath = "/sys/devices/virtual/gpio";
```

points to the new path:

```
sysFsPath = "/sys/class/gpio";
```

#### Solution 3

Add line `device_tree=` in `/boot/config.txt`. That will revert the links to be in the old path.
Make sure you reboot after changing the `config.txt`.

---

Pick your flavor :)

### Edit:

I've fixed both [**pi-gpio**](https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio) ([pull request #34](https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio/pull/34)) and [**gpio-admin**](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin) ([pull request #7](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin/pull/7)) in a manner so that both the old and the new paths are supported. Hopefully, those pull requests are merged soon...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as Matthew and after trying this solution I could see that Saran's fix had already been implemented into the "npm pi-pgio".

If you're still having this problem this solution worked for me.
You need to update the path in gpio-admin.

First Download gpio-admin and open source code (I used nano, but any editor will do)

```
$git clone https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin
$nano quick2wire-gpio-admin/src/gpio-admin.c
```

Check this file and make sure that the paths are updated. Update the `function allow_access_by_user()` the path needs to be updated to `"/sys/class/gpio/gpio%u/%s"`

Now navigate into the folder and install

```
$cd quick2wire-gpio-admin
$make
$sudo make install
```

Note: you may need to add yourself as a user

```
$sudo add adduser $USERNAME gpio
```

Hope this helps save some headaches!