# GPIO doesn't work, error: "Error when trying to open pin 11"

Tags: gpio, node.js, pi-gpio

I connected a LED to pin 11 as per [this guide](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gpio-examples/tux-crossing/gpio-examples-1-a-single-led/). And this works in the terminal to turn it on and off:

```
gpio mode 0 out
gpio write 0 1
gpio write 0 0
```

But when I try to use `pi-gpio`, with this code as per [this guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio):

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");
gpio.open(11, "output", function(err) {     // Open pin 11 for output
    gpio.write(11, 1, function() {          // Set pin 11 high (1)
        gpio.close(11);                     // Close pin 11
    });
});
```

It gives this error message:

```
Error when trying to open pin 11
gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership of /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio17/direction: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong with this? I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7-v7+ #817 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:32:00 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Use https://pinout.xyz to identify pins. WiringPi uses a different numbering system.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  Sounds like the install did not create the links for the libraries as expected.  Try this answer:  [How to change gpio directory for node.js pi-gpio?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27953/how-to-change-gpio-directory-for-node-js-pi-gpio)

Comment: great, after applying the quick2wire-gpio-admin fix, it doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't light up the LED :(

Comment: Can you try the same test on another PI?

Comment: @growlf could you include more detail in your answer, the link might answer the question, but if does not work at a later date your answer is useless